# i have a table view in root view class, i want to display a modal view when the user clicks the cell

Tags: xcode, ipad, uitableview, presentmodalviewcontroller

My table views data source and delegate is set to another class (tableModule). Now i wrote the following code to show the modal view:

```
    NewRule *newRuleModalView = [[NewRule alloc] init]; 
newRuleModalView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
newRuleModalView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentModalViewController:newRuleModalView animated:YES];
newRuleModalView.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 750, 1004);
[newRuleModalView release];
```

This code is not working for me.
Then i set the tableview datasource and delegate to self. Then the same code worked for me.
How can i use it in the first situation?
please help me, i'm a fresher to this field.

Comment: Where is the above code? Which method and class is it in? And you dont normally call `viewDidAppear` manually.

Comment: i wrote the above code in tableView:didselectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: also the root view class is rootViewController class. I used the rootViewController's xib for displaying the tableView.
tableModule is the other class, i used this class as the datasource and delegate of the tableView.
NewRule is the third class, which is the class i want to display as the Modal view.
Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `tableModule` class is not a view controller, and (I think) is not the currently visible view controller, then you can't call `presentModalViewController:` on it. If you've put this code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` in your view controller, and the view controller is not the delegate of the table view, it will never get called.

If you want to keep a separate object as your table view's delegate and data source, your table view's delegate (`tableModule`) needs to have a pointer to your view controller, so it can tell the view controller to present the modal view.

Could you possibly have the datasource as `tableModule` and the delegate as your view controller, or do you need information from `tableModule` to implement the delegate methods?

From your comments, you'd need the following:

- Create a property on `tableModule`, of your `rootViewController` type
- When creating `tableModule`, set `tableModule.rootViewController = self`
- In your did select row method, instead of `[self presentModal...`, do `[self.rootViewController presentModal...`

Comment: i wrote the following code in rootViewController's viewDidLoad

Comment: tableModule *tm = [tableModule alloc] init];
         [displayTableView setDelegate:tm];
         [displayTableView setDatasource:tm];

Comment: my tableModule class is a subclass of UITableViewController.

Comment: OK, but if `tableModule` isn't presented or visible on the screen, I don't think you can ask it to present a modal view controller. This seems like a complicated structure - why isn't `tableModule` your root view controller?

Comment: I understand, but how can i present the modal view from the did select?

Comment: also i can't use the tableviews datasource and delegate as root view, because i'm using two tables in the root view, and i use the rootview as the datasource and delegate of the other table, with same feature.

Comment: That doesn't stop you, all the delegate methods pass the table view as a parameter so you can act accordingly depending on which one you are being called for.

Comment: Thank you for spending your valuable time for me.
I'm working with your idea, i'll check and update you. Thanks...